# How to fetch/rebase specific branch on current one?

Tags: git

I'm having an structure like this:

```
master
ticketNumber01
ticketNumber02
```

So my `ticketNumber01` branch was created from `master`

`ticketNumber02` is created from `ticketNumber01`

how could I get the latest from `master` and also from `ticketNumber01` using `git fetch / rebase` on my current `ticketNumber02` branch?

Comment: `git fetch` by default will download changes from ALL remote branches.

Comment: Git fetch does get the latest. What’s the actual problem? Your list is not a “structure”, and there is no such thing as “changes” in git. Draw or paste an actual gitk diagram. Explain the goal in terms of actual SHA numbers. Otherwise it is not clear why the answer is not fetch and merge or similar.

Comment: sorry I meant to use `git fetch`and then `git rebase` for getting those changes on my current branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using this:

```
# in branch ticketNumber02
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/ticketNumber01
git rebase origin/master
```

with that I was able to properly update my branch using `fetch` / `rebase`

using `git fetch origin` gets updated the reference for all branches.

then using `git rebase origin/<branchName>` rebases any branch on current one

Answer (score -1):

You need to use git merge after you fetch.

```
git fetch
```

It should fetch all the branches to your system, then you need to checkout to those branches and pull for latest changes.

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

Then checkout to desired branch where you want to merge **master** changes.
Merge the changes

```
git checkout ticketNumber02
git merge master
```

Same for **ticketNumber1**

Answer (score -1):

So `git fetch` is used only for fetching the repo, what you are looking for is a `git merge`, to merge changes into one branch. You can add `ticketNumber01` changes into master like this

```
git checkout master
git merge ticketNumber01
```

If you need to merge multiple branches into master, eg. ticketNumber01 and ticketNumber02 you can do like this

```
git checkout master
git merge ticketNumber01 ticketNumber02
```

ps: Remember to pull all branches to make sure they're up to date